# Como crio uma Array dinâmica em C?

Tags: c

Estou começando a programar em C, após ter aprendido as noções básicas em Python.

A princípio estou tentando escrever um programa simples, que lê argumentos do input e os imprime de maneira inversa, por exemplo, "olá mundo" teria como output "odnum álo"

Em Python eu escreveria algo como:

```
A = []
for line in sys.stdin:
  A.append(line)
for i in reversed(array):
  print(i)
```

Mas em C eu não sei como criar uma lista sem especificar uma dimensão fixa. Para escrever o programa acima em C, passando os argumentos do stdin para uma array e depois imprimi-la começando pelo final, tenho algo assim em mente:

```
int c;
int i = 0;
int array;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) 
{
  array[i] = c;
  i++;
}

for (int j = array.size; j > 0; j--) 
{
   printf("%s", array[j]);
}
```

Como se cria uma lista que possa ficar recebendo elementos até o EOF, para utilizar no código exemplo acima?

Comment: Declare `array` como um ponteiro para int e faça uma alocação dinâmica como malloc/calloc/realoc de <stdlib.h>.

Comment: Pesquise sobre alocação dinâmica de memória. Para a implementação, pesquise sobre as funções `malloc`, `free` e `realloc`.

Comment: eu li sobre essas funções, mas na documentação fala que malloc `aloca o número especificado de bytes`, isso não significa que ela ainda mantém um limite pre definido?

Comment: Você pode, por exemplo, alocar um elemento com malloc e a cada novo elemento que quiser adicionar fazer um realloc. Ou ainda utilizar uma lista encadeada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mas em C eu não sei como criar uma lista sem especificar uma dimensão fixa.

Listas como as do Python não existem na linguagem C. Há apenas estruturas de dados mais simples.

Você precisa criar sua própria estrutura de dados se quiser uma lista dinâmica que comporta qualquer número de elementos. Os programadores que escreveram o CPython fizeram a mesma coisa.

> Como se cria uma lista que possa ficar recebendo elementos até o EOF, para utilizar no código exemplo acima?

É preciso alocar a quantidade certa de memória para guardar todos os elementos. A quantidade de elementos só é revelada durante a execução do programa, no momento que `getchar()` retorna `EOF`.

Para solucionar isso, faz-se necessário criar uma estrutura de dados que é capaz de expandir dinamicamente sua capacidade durante a execução do algoritmo:

```
struct lista {
    size_t quantidade;
    size_t capacidade;
    char *elementos;
} lista;
```

Usando a função `malloc`, podemos pedir para o sistema operacional alocar uma quantidade inicial de memória para nossa lista:

```
#define CAPACIDADE_INICIAL 8

lista.quantidade = 0;
lista.capacidade = CAPACIDADE_INICIAL;
lista.elementos = malloc(CAPACIDADE_INICIAL);
```

Podemos então ler os elementos um por um até receber `EOF`:

```
int retorno;

while (EOF != (retorno = getchar())) {
    lista.elementos[lista.quantidade++] = retorno;
}
```

A lista tem inicialmente 0 elementos e capacidade pra 8 elementos. Pode-se utilizar o contador de elementos como o índice da lista, incrementando-o toda vez que um elemento é adicionado.

O que acontece quando a quantidade iguala a capacidade? Quer dizer que chegamos nos limites da lista atual e vamos precisar expandir a memória por ela comportada antes de adicionar novos elementos.

É possível fazer isso com a função `realloc`:

```
if (lista.quantidade >= lista.capacidade) {
    lista.capacidade += CAPACIDADE_INICIAL;
    lista.elementos = realloc(lista.elementos, lista.capacidade);
}
```

Toda vez que a lista fica cheia até sua capacidade máxima, o sistema expande essa capacidade máxima e aloca mais memória para a lista poder comportar essa nova capacidade máxima.

Quando receber `EOF`, a lista estará preenchida com todos os elementos lidos e o código poderá prosseguir com a escrita dos elementos em ordem reversa.

Comment: estou conseguindo fazer funcionar, obrigado pela explicação detalhada. Só não entendi porque a capacidade_inicial é igual a 8 no início

Comment: @Pirategull, é apenas um valor arbitrário. Poderia ser 0, 1, 10, 100, 1000... Quanto menor a capacidade inicial, maior a quantidade de realocações de memória, operações custosas e que se encontram dentro de um laço. Quanto maior a capacidade inicial, maior o gasto de memória inicial. O ideal é advinhar um número próximo à quantidade de elementos na prática e alocar capacidade o mais próximo possível desse número. Existem maneiras mais eficientes de implementar essa expansão de capacidade, mas são menos didádicas.

Comment: comprendi, eu nao conhecia sobre o #define. sua resposta tem me ajudado tremendamente, estou estudando tudo aos pouquinhos. Se não for pedir demais, você poderia escrever a sintaxe do printf() para imprimir os elementos da lista quando se trata de ponteiros?

Comment: @Pirategull, como temos uma lista de `char`s, o formato é o mesmo do `char` comum: `printf("%c", lista.elementos[i]);`. Leia a documentação para ver mais opções.